# how to add a new xml node in vbscript

Tags: xml, dom, vbscript

I have the following XML file and I want to add a new child inside ComputerAudit.How to do this using VBScript ?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
-<ITChecklist>
-    <ComputerAudit>
        <ComputerName>atl-ws-001</ComputerName>
        <AuditDate>6/24/2014</AuditDate>
     </ComputerAudit>
</ITChecklist>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763742%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and this sample code:

```
>> Set o = CreateObject("msxml2.domdocument")
>> o.loadXml "<a><b><c/></b></a>"
>> Set n = o.createElement("d")
>> n.appendChild o.createTextNode("pipapo")
>> o.documentElement.firstChild.appendChild n
>> WScript.Echo o.xml
>>
<a><b><c/><d>pipapo</d></b></a>
```

(after reading the general intro, lookup the methods used, come up with detailed specs/a plan, ask specific question if necessary)